# Kotlin main function named arguments

Tags: kotlin, program-entry-point, args

Im writing a cli util and for this i need to start my kotlin program with some named arguments as you would with lots of cli programs. i.e.:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4`

Im calling this named named arguments since the name of the argument `input.mp4` is `-i`.

What would be the correct approach (or is there some kind of library, i know Python has some libraries to handle this).

As far as i know the only way to grab the arguments would be with:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
```

But those are just in a array seperated by spaces.

preferably i would retrieve some kind of map with key values. for the named args.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, you need a library for that. You'll find many if you google "kotlin cli library" or "java cli library".

Comment: Also, they're not necessarily separated by spaces.  The shell does the necessary word-splitting and creates the array of arguments passed to your program.  (Most shells allow spaces to be quoted, for example.  Or if you're launching your program some other way, then that will create the array instead.)  The Kotlin runtime simply converts that array to String objects and passes it to your `main()` function.

Comment: here every arguments get parsed as string separated by space as @gidds said , you can try accessing element by index and parse input yourself or use a cli library like [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-cli)

Comment: In addition to the official [kotlinx-cli](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-cli) (the version isn't 1.0 yet), there is also a good library: [clikt](https://github.com/ajalt/clikt). You can find more libraries using [kotlin.link](https://kotlin.link).